# Is this the most secure encryption/hashing system?

Tags: encryption, web-application, hash

I've been doing some research regarding password security and after reading several topics and the Kerckhoff's principle. I came up with what I believe is a really secure system regarding online security:

An offline/local encryption/hashing server. Imagine this: a user registers himself on the website but instead of the current site hashing and storing the password, the site sends an request to the hashing server (which contains the hashing algorithm and the salt). *I have not quite figured out the most secure way of communication between servers just yet*.

The hashing server then responds with the hashed password that the site then stores in the database. This way even if the hacker knows the system depending on how you configured the hashing server (*I am also lacking a bit of information about configuring servers*) the hacker won't be able to figure out your hashing/salt.

I would appreciate any feedback or criticism regarding my so called 'system'

Comment: You've described a less secure OAUTH system? What is gained by hashing on the remote server? Are you aware that knowing the hashing algorithm or salt is not supposed to reduce the security of the password?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**  Yes, if done properly, the system you've designed should provide a small security gain, but it probably isn't the best option.

---

The expanded version:

When we design security into a system, we first develop a threat model, and then we figure out how our system is going to mitigate those specific threats.  So, the question for you is:  "What is the threat you're trying to protect the system from, and does this design reasonably mitigate that threat?"  where "reasonably" means effectively reduces the threat to a acceptable level of risk without adding excessive cost or complexity.

So, it seems to me that the specific threat you're trying to protect against is an attacker dumping password hashes and salts from the web application database.

If we want to stipulate that an attacker has the ability to query the database in the context of the application, this is a valid concern.  However, generally, I'd suggest that we *don't* in fact stipulate that.  That leads to the attacker being able to access a wide variety of potentially privileged data, and adding complexity to the system to protect this one target (hashes and salts) without adding complexity to protect the other privileged data doesn't make sense...Unless this data is significantly more valuable than any other data in the database.   Instead, we would generally want our threat model to enumerate the more generic threat of an attacker illegitimately accessing the database, and protect against that as a whole.

However, let's go ahead and add this to our threat model as a valid threat that needs mitigation, since your mitigating mechanism is what you really had a question about in the first place.

So, is moving password verification to a separate system, and having that system only expose an API providing a password oracle a valid way to defend against this threat?   Yes.  It is.  Isolating sensitive data in special purpose hardened systems is standard pattern in information security, like the way we store secret keys in hardware security modules.  In this case, however, it's a lot of cost and complexity to add for a fairly narrow threat, so I don't know that I would generally recommend it, but it certainly has some (small) potential security advantages.

However, this is not the only mechanism you have available to reduce this threat.   Depending on your database engine, you may be able to use something like stored procedures to verify passwords for you, and at minimum deny the application access to the password hashes, so they can't be dumped, and salts can only be retrieved individually.  Potentially you could even have the the database compute the verification for you, and not allow the application access to either hashes or salts, achieving effectively the exact same goals you laid out, without the complexity of an additional system.

Or, you could go the wildly popular route of identity and authentication federation, and do away with storing password hashes and salts at all.  In an enterprise setting you may have a federation provider that can allow you to delegate authentication, and deal instead with something like a SAML token, and in the web world, you can use OAUTH and let companies like Google and Facebook worry about credential management and authentication, and you need have no passwords at all, eliminating this particular threat entirely.

Comment: I don't have a particular threat I'm trying to protect myself from, I am just trying to figure out an all-round secure system. Imagine I own a company with a couple of dev's, and these devs know the salt, hashing algorithm and database login information to some extend. Imagine I fire one of these dev's and he doesnt agree with it and wants mess up the day of my customers, he would have significantly easier time trying to break the hashing if he knows the algoritm and the salt. But maybe I've taken Kerckhoff's principle a bit too serious

Answer (score 0):

> An offline/local encryption/hashing server. Imagine this an user register himself >on the website but instead of the current site hashing and storing the password.

This exposes the password to a unknown server, with unknown security for the password itself. Its better to NEVER send an password over the wire at all. you could use a java script hashing script for this.

> The site sends an request to the hashing server (which contains the hashing >algorith and the salt). Im have not quite figured out the most secury way of >communication between servers just yet.

2 connections means 2 lines to eavesdrop. so it will always be less secure than 1 connection. (and both would yield login credentials so both are interesting)

> The hashing server then responds with the hashed password which the site then >stores in the database. This way even if the hacker knows the system depending on >how you configured the hashing server (I am also lacking a bit of information about >configuring servers) the hacker wont be able to figure out your hashing/salt.

This could also be tackled by simply rehashing the hash with a salted hash. (basically adding a salt to the hash before you validate it so a stolen hash from the DB does not yield an access token.)

Its not an bad idea. but your idea does not add a lot of security IMHO.

maybe someone else has a diffrent view/ pointers.

Comment: I am wondering how it would be possible to eavesdrop the connection going to the hashing server if the server would be configured to only provide service to certain servers within the local network. -edit: unless ofcourse the network is infected

Comment: You said "the site sends an request to the hashing server" (sic) which implies that the site has remote connectivity to the local hashing server..

Comment: From a security standpoint, any connection outside of a protected environment is insecure (so when leaving the confines of your server is allready insecure) unless protected through other means.